# Can I return 2 different data types in javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, return

Given 2 conditions I want to either return an object or bool as follows:

```js
function foo() {

  if (a==b) {
    return {
      bool: bool,
      string: "string"
    };
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function callFoo() {

  var obj = foo();
}
```

This seems to be failing for me.  IE won't hit breakpoints for some reason either so its hard for me to trouble shoot.

Regards.

Comment: Function definitions need parameter lists. (you also never defined `bool`)

Comment: why -1 on this question?

Comment: Typo question (off-topic)

Comment: typo?  off topic?  how do you figure?

Comment: It's failing with a syntax error because `callFoo` doesn't have a parameter list. Does it work as intended if you add one?

Comment: `if (true)`  This is always going to return the first one,..  Your not getting mixed up with C++ union type are you..

Comment: It should be `function callFoo () {` not `function callFoo {`. I'm VTC as typo

Comment: All, that was a typo on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Javascript you can return different types from the same function. Take a look at the following example:

```js
function getAnswer(input) {
  if (input == "foo") {
    return "bar";
  }
  else if (input == true) {
    return true;
  }
  else if (input == 100) {
    return {
      type:"number",
      value:100,
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// Different inputs
console.log(getAnswer("foo"));
console.log(getAnswer(true));
console.log(getAnswer(100));
console.log(getAnswer(false));
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  My whole issue was so dumb.  I called function like this:  var foo = foo();   Forgetting that everything thing is an object in js (except string) so lesson learned, cant have create var with same function name in same scope....this ruined my night.  I had to write that last line of code before I was about to call it a day and it broke everything lol.....thanks for the confirmation, made me reevaluate

Comment: @JeffOrris no worries, believe me I've been there lol, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood you, but I am not sure. Fix me if I'm wrong:

```js
function foo(a, b) {

  if (a==b) {
    return {
      bool: true,
      string: "string"
    };
  }
  return false;
}


function callFoo(a, b) {
  var obj = foo(a, b);
  console.log(obj);
}

callFoo(1, 1);
callFoo(1, 2);
```